# JPA Criteria select from another query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to select information from another query, like:

```
SELECT user.user_id, product.first_time
FROM USER AS user
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(product.first_time) as first_time,
                   product.user_id
            FROM PRODUCT AS product
            GROUP BY (product.user_id)
           ) product
ON user.user_id = product.user_id
```

but i don't know how to create a Criteria Query to execute it.
Can I execute it with Criteria API?

Comment: JPQL and JPA Criteria don't allow join to a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html

need to create metaclasses your's entities.

example, your's service class:

```
@Service("jpaCustomerService")
@Repository
@Transactional

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<CustomersEntity> findByCriteriaQuery(String name){
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<CustomersEntity> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(CustomersEntity.class);
        Root<CustomersEntity> customersEntityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(CustomersEntity.class);
        customersEntityRoot.fetch(CustomersEntity_.animal, JoinType.LEFT);
        criteriaQuery.select(customersEntityRoot).distinct(true);
        Predicate criteria = cb.conjunction();
        if (!name.isEmpty()){
            Predicate p = cb.equal(customersEntityRoot.get(CustomersEntity_.name), name);
        criteria = cb.and(criteria, p);
        }
        criteriaQuery.where(criteria);
        List<CustomersEntity> result = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

and your's controller or your's main:

```
public static void criteriaExample(GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx){
        CustomerService service = ctx.getBean("jpaCustomerService", CustomerService.class);
        List<CustomersEntity> creteriaResult = service.findByCriteriaQuery("NCI-3");
        for (CustomersEntity customer : creteriaResult){
            System.out.println(customer);
            if (!customer.getAnimal().isEmpty())
            for (AnimalsEntity animal : customer.getAnimal()){
                System.out.println(animal);
            }
        }
    }
```

CustomersEntity_ - metamodel class. No needs SQL-query.

and your's infs is:

```
public interface CustomerService {
List<CustomersEntity> findByCriteriaQuery(String name);}
```

Comment: but it doesn't answer the question. You've simply said "there is a static metamodel generator for Criteria". It doesn't answer how to create a Criteria equivalent of that SQL ... which cannot be done directly since subqueries are invalid in a JOIN like that

Comment: "NCI-3" - name your's entities in db.